# Using Http::withBasicAuth() to automatically login

Tags: laravel

I have 2 different code bases, one is the client facing code and the other is the api code. One of the things I need to be able to do is log in to the api code and then do what I need it to do. The problem I'm having is that, I'm not able to log in to the api code, all I get is a login form. This is my code

```
$endpoint = 'backcode.api';
$cookies = request()->cookies->all();
$response = Http::withBasicAuth('testuser@email.com', 'password')
                    ->withCookies($cookies, $endpoint)
                    ->get($endpoint.'/dashboard');
return $response;
```

I had to use the solution in [Laracast](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/code-review/laravel-sail-bridge-network-does-not-allow-connections-between-containers) for me to be able to have my 2 containers talk to each other, but even though if I do something like this

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    dd('im here');
});
```

I do hit it. It's only when I try to "Log in" that I'm having issues with.